# pyTorch nn.Conv2D use twice lead to an error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am using pytorch training a model. Here is the code:

```
def forward(self, x):
        H, W = self.input_resolution
        B_, shuf_size_2, win_size_2, C = x.shape
        shuf_size = int(shuf_size_2 ** 0.5)
        win_size = int(win_size_2 ** 0.5)
        B = B_ // (H//shuf_size//win_size) // (W//shuf_size//win_size)

        msg_token = window_reverse(
            x[:, :, 0].unsqueeze(2), 1, shuf_size, H//win_size, W//win_size, nchw=True)

        msg_token = self.reduction(msg_token).permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
        msg_token = self.norm(msg_token)
        if msg_token.shape[1] >= self.nxt_shuf_size:
            msg_token = window_partition(msg_token, 1, self.nxt_shuf_size)

        x = window_reverse(x[:, :, 1:], win_size, shuf_size, H, W, nchw=True)
        x = self.reduction(x).permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
        x = self.norm(x)

        if x.shape[1] // win_size >= self.nxt_shuf_size:
            x = window_partition(x, win_size, self.nxt_shuf_size)
        else:
            x = window_partition(x, win_size, 1)

        x = torch.cat((msg_token, x), dim=2)

        return x
```

In this code, `self.reduction` is a Conv2D layer:

```
self.reduction = nn.Conv2d(dim, 2 * dim, 3, 2, 1)
```

where `dim` is 64

the tensor `msg_token` has the shape of `[128,64,8,8]` before sent into `self.reduction`

the tensor `x` has the shape of `[128,64,56,56]` before sent into `self.reduction`

But when the code runs here:

```
x = self.reduction(x).permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
```

It raises an error:

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
tuple index out of range
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/models/msg_transformer.py", line 298, in forward
x = self.reduction(x).permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/models/msg_transformer.py", line 384, in forward
x = self.downsample(x)
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/models/msg_transformer.py", line 579, in forward_features
x = layer(x)
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/models/msg_transformer.py", line 585, in forward
x = self.forward_features(x)
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/main.py", line 168, in train_one_epoch
outputs = model(samples)
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/main.py", line 134, in main
train_one_epoch(config, model, criterion, data_loader_train, optimizer, epoch, mixup_fn, lr_scheduler)
File "/home/yun/Coding/MSG-Transformer/main.py", line 356, in
main(config)
```

I found that if I sent `x` into `self.reduction` before senting `msg_token` into `self.reduction`, this error would be raised by `msg_token = self.reduction(msg_token).permute(0, 2, 3, 1)` instead. Could anyone help?

Comment: Check the tensor shape **after** `self.reduction(x)`

Comment: self.reduction(x) would raise that error, not caused by permute(). thus the program would terminated before getting the correct result of self.reduction(x)